# lib to read a DVD FS (data disc)

Tags: c++, hardware, io, disk, dvd

I am thinking i might want to port a lib to read a DVD filesystem. I am not talking about movies but datadisc. Theres existing code for me to do raw reads from the disc. I need code that request this data and allow me to browse files on the disc. What lib can i use for this?

-edit- NOTE: I am using an OSless hardware. Ppl seem to miss that but Alnitak caught it and gave me a great answer :)

Comment: We didn't "miss" it -- you didn't *say* it.

Comment: ...which is to say -- you explicitly asked for a library, but didn't explain why. Folks often end up "going down rabbit holes" doing things the hard way when an easy way is available; explaining *why* you need to do it the hard way means getting better answers.

Comment: Charles Duffy: I see. I assumed the hardware tag was all i needed to say. Also the answers that said use the os didnt answer my question

Comment: Never count on people to know how to answer your question based on tags. (About the only thing you can count on is that it expresses a *preference* for what programming language you want the answer in, but there are even times when this is ignored in the interests of expediency, and it's assumed that the questioner can figure out how to port the answer.) The "hardware" tag is also pretty vague.

Comment: @Ken: The question would be too weird if i was asking how to read the FS with or through an OS. Did you know i meant raw IO? Alnitak didnt seem to flinch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `libudf` which is part of GNU [`libcdio`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to browse files, why not let your operating system do the heavy lifting? Given that a modern OS will already have everything it needs to mount filesystems from DVDs -- and that there will be numerous people already using and debugging this code, as opposed to a smaller and more focused userbase for a userspace library such as libdvdread -- it seems silly not to leverage them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the same I/O libs you'd use to read files from a hard disk?